# Android listview, current item counter

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

In my android application I have a listview which displays dynamic data according to the user query.

The problem is I need to display in the footer, which Item the user currently have selected(while Scrolling through the listview).

I Implemented `OnItemSelectedListener` and can catch the scrolling position. 
I initially defined a global variable and asigned it to -1.

`int selectedRowIndex = -1;`

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,long arg3) {

    selectedRowIndex = arg2;    
    footer.setText(String.valueOf(selectedRowIndex+1)+ " of " + String.valueOf(companyList.size()));
}
```

The problem is, when the page initially load and even no item have yet selected(Scroll), the selectedRowIndex value had become 0(The first Item in the listview). I cant understand why it happen and can anyone suggest a way to implement this .

Thanks inadvance

Edits

```
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="match_parent">

             <TextView android:text="TextView" 
                  android:id="@+id/noCompanysFound_Message" 
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:visibility="gone"
                  android:textStyle="italic"
                  android:layout_marginTop="10dp">
                  </TextView>

            <ListView android:layout_width="match_parent"    
                      android:layout_height="match_parent" 
                      android:id="@+id/companylistView"
                      android:listSelector="@drawable/item_focus_bkg"
                      android:layout_above="@+id/footer_linearLayout"
                      android:focusable="false">
                      </ListView>                         

             <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/footer_linearLayout" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:background="@drawable/bottom_bkg" android:gravity="center_horizontal">         
                <TextView android:text="Footer Text" 
                          android:id="@+id/companylistFooterTextView" 
                          android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                          android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                          android:textColor="#FFFFFF">
                          </TextView>       
            </LinearLayout>        


        </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: cypressious  is right just debug your programm and look onItemSelected() method.

Answer (score 1):

I think whenever your activity created your `listview get Focused` and the `first row will be selected` that's why  `listview's onItemSelected()` will be surely called once and the index of first row of list is 0 so in code

```
selectedRowIndex = arg2; became selectedRowIndex = 0;
```

If I am wrong then give me suggestion or let me know.

Comment: Hi user370305, Yes that's the problem. I have added a code to give focus to a button in the page as the last statement in "onStart()" method. and in "onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus)" event for listview, when forcus lose I gave selectedRowIndex = -1; But still selectedRowIndex value is 0.

Comment: Hi I did that too. But still the same

Comment: Hi, Still no difference. I can't just figure out why.

Comment: HI, just added the XML layout as well